# Tensorflow how to read tensor from OpenCV image frame

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision

Tensorflow provides a `label_image.py` implementation for inference of an image. This works great for images on disk. But i have a case wherein I am reading a streaming video from a webcam and I would like to run inference on each image frame to detect the object in the camera feed.

Currently [label_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py#L38) only accepts an image on disk and using `read_tensor_from_image_file` converts it into a Tensor. How do i get a Tensor with the necessary pre-processing as being done in `read_tensor_from_image_file` from the Open CV image frame that i have in memory?

Comment: You need numpy array for image. It can come after reading from file or from network.

Comment: Yes what i get from OpenCV is a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways. you can

1. feed numpy array to tensorflow, considering opencv python wrapper read image as numpy array,
2. `tf.py_func` is useful when you don't want to feed your input because of performance issue.
3. Also, if you use c++, you can define a custom op to wrap opencv mat to a tensor.